# Unable to refresh database after deleting a row

Tags: android

I am using SQLiteDatabase in android. I am not able to refersh my listview after deleting a row.
My code is as follows:

```
    public void delete(String i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns= new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID,KEY_FHR,KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_AGE};
    Cursor c= our_db.query(KEY_TABLE, columns, null, null,null, null, null);
    our_db.delete(KEY_TABLE, KEY_NAME+ "="+"\'"+i+"\'", null) ;
    c.requery();

}
```

I call it from a viewholder in efficientadapter. Below is the code where I call it:

```
        holder.del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos=position;
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final long newpos;
                    sql_get db = new sql_get(c);
                    db.open();

                    db.delete(DATA[pos]);               
                    notifyDataSetChanged();                     
                    db.close();
                }
            });
```

Can anyone help me finding out the problem. It doesn't give any error. it just deleted the row but doesn't update the view.

Here is the adapter i used:

```
    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mIcon1;
    private Bitmap mIcon2;
    private Bitmap mIcon3;
    private Bitmap mIcon4;

    Context c;
    int window;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.c=context;
        // Icons bound to the rows.
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
        mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
        mIcon3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.del1);
        mIcon4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.edit);
    }       
    public int getCount() {
        return DATA.length;
    }       
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }   
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }       
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;
        //int i=0;


            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.del=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
            holder.edit=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon2);

            window=position;
            holder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                private int pos=position;

                //private int pos = position; 
                public void onClick(View v) { 

                    System.out.println(window);
                    sql_get db = new sql_get(c);
                    db.open();
                    String ret_id= db.getid(DATA[pos]);
                    String ret_name = db.getname(DATA[pos]);                        
                    String ret_age= db.getage(DATA[pos]); 
                    String ret_fhr= db.getfhr(DATA[pos]);                       
                    String[] result = {ret_id,ret_name,ret_age,ret_fhr};
                    db.close();
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                    b.putStringArray("key",result); 
                    Intent i =new Intent(c,Tabs.class);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    c.startActivity(i)  ;
                    Toast.makeText(c, getItemId(position)+""+" Click- text " +pos+" "+ret_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            });                 
            holder.del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos=position;
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final long newpos;                      
                    sql_get db = new sql_get(c);
                    db.open();
                    db.delete(DATA[pos]);                       
                    notifyDataSetChanged();                     
                    db.close();                     
                    Toast.makeText(c, "deleting " + DATA[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                      
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }           
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);
        holder.del.setImageBitmap(mIcon3);
        holder.edit.setImageBitmap(mIcon4);
        return convertView;     
    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView del;
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
        ImageView edit;
    }       
}
```

Comment: After deleting the row you have to get all data from database and bind it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. As said above, I had to change the DATA object.
I used the following commands to achieve it.

```
db.open();                                      
db.delete(DATA[pos]);           
DATA=db.getdata();
DATA_NAME=db.getname();
DATA_AGE=db.getage();
DATA_FHR=db.getfhr();                                                   
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the row also from the object holding the data for the list view..

Comment: @ nunu, can you tell me how to do that.. I am quite new to android

Comment: Hello, I tried everything, but still this problem persists. I assign the values of data object as null, the values disappear but it still shows empty rows. can you please tell me how to delete the Data object?

Answer (score 1):

I think you also have to remove the same data from adapter and then use your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method. That worked for me...